# Wikipedia API in JSON

Tags: json, wikipedia-api

Is there a Wikipedia API available to fetch its contents in plain JSON if possible without [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode), or *Wikipedia* special code! Something similar to YouTube's JSON API like [this](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=baseball&start-index=1&max-results=1&alt=json).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at *[MediaWiki API help](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php)*. There you can find all the necessary information. You can choose the format of responses among the following list:

```
json, jsonfm, php, phpfm, wddx, wddxfm, xml, xmlfm, yaml, yamlfm
rawfm, txt, txtfm, dbg, dbgfm, dump, dumpfm, none
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the opportunity to consume Wikipedia pages through a wrapper API like [JSONpedia](http://jsonpedia.org/). It works both live (ask for the current JSON representation of a Wikipedia page) and storage based (query multiple pages previously ingested in [Elasticsearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch) and [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Windows `curl` statement that returns a JSON response of a Wikipedia entry (Albert Einstein). Most of the HTML markup is removed although <ref> remains. It also contains some Wikipedia markup.

```
curl "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&redirects&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=Albert+Einstein" -o curl-wiktionary-result.json
```

Use this [jq command](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) to drill down into the "content" property:

```
jq ".query.pages[].revisions[].content" < curl-wiktionary-result.json
```